# Is there a noun for the general, solely negative, discrimination of any kind of group?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

Is there a noun for the general, solely negative, discrimination of any kind of group?

Like, a word that encompasses misandry, misogyny, anti-semitism, the common use of both "racist" and "sexist", etc.

If there is no such word, that is a valid answer too.

Comment: @Malandy - positive discrimination? “Discrimination is the practice of treating one person or group of people less fairly or less well than other people or groups.” https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discrimination - The unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discrimination

Comment: In human social affairs, discrimination is treatment or consideration of, or making a distinction in favor of or against, a person based on the group, class, or category to which the person is perceived to belong. ***These include age, colour, convictions for which a pardon has been granted or a record suspended, disability, ethnicity, family status, gender identity, genetic characteristics, marital status, nationality, race, religion, sex, and sexual orientation.*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrimination

Comment: @JamesRandom - You don't have to hate a group, though... ... Should probably say that a answer of "No, there is no such word" is acceptable...

Comment: @Malandy - I know that “in favour” may sound positive, but note that we are talking  about treating unfairly favoring someone over somebody else. Treat white people  better than black for instance...etc.

Comment: When discrimination is positive, it is almost always referred to as "positive discrimination". I don't think the phrase "negative discrimination" is used much, if at all. The opposite of  "positive discrimination" is "discrimination".

Comment: @Malandy - I think you are confusing discrimination with differentiation.

Comment: The very fact that we have "positive discrimination" is proof enough that *discrimination* in and of itself is by default negative. Furthermore, since when is it "discrimination of", anyway. That's what ESL learners always say. And you always have to correct them that in English it's "discrimination against". And that *against* right there really drives the point home that it's not a good thing at all.

Comment: The dictionaries quoted show that the word 'discrimination' has now become almost wholly negative. But it need not be: consider "He was a discriminating collector of antique silver". That is, he could distinguish the very good stuff from the rest: a positive attribute in an antique collector.

Comment: The problem I see is in the adjective, not the noun. Many words have been proposed, discrimination, bigotry, etc., but you cannot say you are a discriminating person (it would actually have a positive meaning). You can say you are a bigot, like you can say racist or sexist, or intolerant, but not mistreating, discriminating, etc.

Comment: Reminder to everyone: Comments are for clarifying questions and suggestions to improve the asker's question, not for suggesting answers. That's what answers are for. Comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do.

Comment: @Malandy (a) If you already know that discrimination is not always negative, why select it as the correct answer? Prejudice and bigotry are both better answers. (b) **You really should add some example sentences to clarify exactly what you're looking for**.

Comment: @Lly - (a) Because "Discrimination" seemed to be the closest the English language had. Until Tuffy answered with "Prejudice"... Which might be even better, what with getting 10 votes, even though I didn't vote. (b) All that seems to do, is specify precisely what kind of noun I might want? I don't really know a good sentence to clarify with, but I like the answers I'm getting anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

bigotry
[big-uh-tree]
noun, plural big·ot·ries.

1   stubborn and complete intolerance of any creed, belief, or opinion that differs from one's own.

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bigotry)

Comment: This wouldn't cover the examples the OP gave though, would it? Sex and ethnicity are not creeds, beliefs, nor opinions. Also, one can discriminate based on shared traits. I've known people that discriminate on others because they're of the same ethnicity.

Comment: I think that dictionary entry is not general enough. Bigotry does encompass sexism and racism, perhaps consider changing to MW: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigotry

Comment: Okay, yeah. Bigotry is much better than the broader Discrimination.

Answer (score 27):

The trouble with *discrimination* as the kind of general term you seem to seek is its wider use.

Discrimination is a quality I hope I have.  I hope I exercise discrimination in the kinds of literature, art and music I like, in the kinds of political rhetoric to which I pay attention, the charities I support.  There is nothing wrong with discriminating between the better and the worse, even though we should also be open to different tastes from our own.

The word that always has a negative connotation is **prejudice**.

Comment: It seems, according to the Cambridge dictionary, "prejudice" is basically an near-exact synonym for "discrimination"?

Comment: Except that discrimination, unlike prejudice, is not always derogatory.

Comment: Okay, you've convinced me? Prejudice is at least as close as "Discrimination" to what I would've wanted. So, you're getting the Accept due to popular vote, basically...

Comment: But isn't "discrimination" the action, while "prejudice" is a belief?

Comment: @Sentry Yes, in relation to behaviour based on prejudice, it is.  On the other hand, the particular phenomena malandy mentions are surely themselves principally attitudinal.

Comment: Though the examples you cite are correct, those are  not within the contexts that the OP  is referring to.

Comment: @Sentry: You're correct, but I'm not sure what you're aiming at. Note that there are other forms of immoral discrimination that are not caused by prejudice. Prejudice implies genuine belief in a false truth - but it doesn't cover cases of disingenuous discrimination; e.g. not allowing women to drive cars, not because you think they can't drive (which would be prejudice), but because you simply want to have less cars on the road (and you're a man who wants an exclusion rule that does not exclude you).

Comment: @Flater Interesting example.  It does not, as I’m sure you realise, meet the examples of OP.  Misandry, mysogeny and even anti-sémitism do not entail action.  Indeed, I would argue that the vandalising of (say) a jewish grave is anti semitic in virtue of its motivation.  Some forms of discrimination are (or used to be) legitimate:  keeping males out of female toilets and vice versa; denying non-communicants to the sacraments; denying certain classes of foreigner rights of residence.  Oddly, we can even argue whether such forms of ‘discrimination’ are DISCRIMINATORY (i.e. based on prejudice).

Comment: @Tuffy: My comment (and example) was more in response to what I suspect Sentry was getting at, rather than trying to reframe the OP's question.

Comment: @Flater: Interesting examples, indeed. The point I was getting at is that "prejudice" is IMHO not a valid answer to OP's question, because "solely negative discrimination" is an action, while "prejudice" is not.

Answer (score 9):

Many words have multiple meanings, or shades of meaning. The word discrimination is often used in a negative sense:

> Discrimination is the practice of treating one person or group of people less fairly or less well than other people or groups.
>
> ...discrimination against immigrants.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discrimination)

The negative meaning is clear from the context and, in some cases, the use of a preposition like "against".

If you are looking for a word that has just the meaning you want, and no other meanings, then you are out of luck: there is no such word. (For this meaning or any other.)

Answer (score 7):

If the discrimination is not negative enough, what about **mistreatment**?
This is also more active than the discrimination, but I think the word can be applied to the groups as well. I can imagine some contexts where it can convey your idea as I understand it.

from mistreat:[mistreat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mistreat)

to treat a person or animal badly, cruelly, or unfairly:

Comment: Oooh... This is nice... But "discrimination" is used more often for groups... So I think that answer is best...

Comment: I have also upvoted the accepted answer, but you used the word discrimination directly in your question, so I thought that you are looking for a different one. I know that the shift in the meaning might be too large to use my answer in all situations.

Comment: Yeah, "discrimination" is not the word I want, but it's apparently the best that English's got.

Answer (score 7):

> **intolerance** [in-tol-er-uh ns] *noun*
>
> **1** lack of tolerance; unwillingness or refusal to tolerate or respect opinions or beliefs contrary to one's own.
>
> **2** unwillingness or refusal to tolerate or respect persons of a different social group, especially members of a minority group.

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intolerance)

Answer (score 5):

contempt
[kuh n-tempt]
noun

1   the feeling with which a person regards anything considered mean, vile, or worthless; disdain; scorn.

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contempt)

Adjective form; contemptuous

Answer (score 4):

PV22 already brought up **bigotry**.  Synonyms include **prejudice**. Perhaps also **chauvinism**, which is now used much more broadly than its original meaning of jingoism, particularly for misogyny.  Someone who believes a particular group of people is superior to others and should rule over them is a **supremacist**.

Someone who thinks people like them should spurn groups of people is a **separatist**; unlike the other words I list, this is a term that radical groups (such as separatist feminists, red-pillers, or Malcolm X in the early ’60s) sometimes use to describe themselves.  When these groups want the separation to be enforced by law, that becomes **apartheid**, which always have negative connotations.  Especially in the United States, **segregation** has historically meant either private businesses refusing to serve members of a group, or laws to prevent some group from participating equally in society.

For what it’s worth, the neutral sense of “discrimination” is nearly extinct.  Years ago, when I was taking economics as an undergrad, the (British) professor got to the topic of “price discrimination” and the (American) students all said, no, discrimination is illegal.  He explained that, in economics, it's just a neutral term for charging any two people different prices, but they weren’t buying it.  In common use today, “discrimination” is some action motivated by prejudice, and doesn’t convey the original, neutral meaning of making distinctions.

Comment: These days, "chauvinism" is used pretty much exclusively for misogyny; a "separatist" is almost certainly going to be understood as somebody who wants their region to become an independent country. And your last paragraph seems to be equating "used in  Britain" with "nearly extinct". Pfft.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think chauvinism is still used similarly to its original meaning, jingoism.  (Not necessarily French.) Any of those words can be qualified, if the meaning isn’t clear in context, as in “Gender Apartheid” or “Black separatists.” Finally, I don’t know how common “discrimination” in the neutral sense is in Britain these days, but “price discrimination” is a piece of jargon from classical economics, not a term in current everyday use.

Comment: I'm certainly not claiming that "neutral" use of "discrimination" is common in British English, but it's not so rare that I can imagine a class of students objecting to its use. The verb form is probably more common and I think people can easily discriminate between cases where it just means "tell the difference between two things, or take different actions according to the situation" and the cases where it means "be racist or sexist or whatever-ist."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the information. I wouldn’t have guessed that college students would’ve objected to the word here either.

Answer (score 2):

**Persecution** seems to fit.

*Persecution is the systematic mistreatment of an individual or group by another individual or group. The most common forms are religious persecution, racism and political persecution, though there is naturally some overlap between these terms.*

Answer (score 1):

How about hater (sometimes spelled h8r in text messages)?

Comment: Hi Henry. Welcome to SE. H8R and Hater is an interesting contemporary suggestion. Did you consider how it’s used these days to describe the slightest disapproval; i.e. P1: “I don’t like your shirt.”, P2: “You are just a hater.”? If it is used in this way, does it really carry the same emphasis on actual destructive hate like racism?